# Chrome extension error - Unexpected illegal token

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this particular line of code

```
var o = JSON.parse(localStorage['options']);
```

localStorage['options'] is an object:

```
{"ads":true,"chat":true,"footer":true,"invite":true,"web":true,"contact":true,"window":true,"icon":t rue,"row":true,"message":true}
```

If I use this code in option.html, nothing wrong will happen. But in background.html, I get the error "unexpected illegal token".

how can I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you set the value on the `browser` site, not on the `background` site.

Both pages have a different `window` object and therefore a different `localStorage` so what happens is that you background page tries to read a value that wasn't set.

Example:

```
> localStorage['foo']
undefined
> JSON.parse(undefined)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

To fix it, you need to set the `localStorage` data in the background page.